# Using WebPy as a static HTTP content server

Tags: static, virtualhost, web.py

How is it possible to tune up WebPy to use it to serve static content for several websites?

I run two websites on one IP using `web.subdomain_application` for name-based virtual hosting. The implied solution for hosting static content is to create a `static/` directory in the directory containing HTTP server script and put all static files from both websited there.

However even if I create sub-directories `site1/` and `site2/` inside  `static/` to organize my resources, it would be possible to request Site1's resources on, say, `http://site2.com/static/site1/foo.css`. It seems natural to me to restrict such cross-site access to resources.

How to serve static stuff for two sites separately on WebPy?

Comment: That internal web server is for development. Use fastcgi or mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use nginx to serve static content, e.g.:

```
location ~ ^/(static(/.*)?)$ {
    alias /srv/http/$1;
}

location / {
    include /etc/nginx/conf/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/my_webapp.sock;
}
```